# My rat is going to die... but when?

Tags: injury

My pet rat Luna has a tumor so I know she's dying but she also has scabs all over her body that hurt her. Would it be kinder to put her out of her misery now or wait until she dies on her own? Rat's and other small rodents do not have the exact same anatomy so I would like a rat based answer. AND SHE'S NOT A CAT EITHER!!!

Comment: I haven't seen anything of the sort.

Comment: @Hannah Ultimately, there is no checklist that gives you "the right answer" depending on how many checkboxes you tick. Pets can live a long time with tumors, but excessive scratching and scabbing are a source of pain and possible negative consequences like inflammation. If you notice serious changes in her behavior like apathy, loss of hunger and thirst or pronounced avoidance of touch that wasn't there before, you must assume that she's in a bad state. Your vet might help you make the right descision.

Comment: I don't have a vet for her because of their short lifespans. And it's expensive. i went there with one of my old rats and she died in the waiting room, but they still charged us $50! I don't have that kind of money. Also she's almost 3 years old so she won't live much longer with or without the tumor. Luna does not like being touched and bites me for it but she wasn't always like this. She never really liked being held but she never used to bite and actively avoid it. And another thing! My rat had those scabs long before her tumor so that isn't the cause of them.

Comment: Whether it's a rat, cat, dog, or any other pet, the guidelines are still the same. I know you're hurting from knowing your pet's time is limited, but please take a look at the answers and how they talk about evaluating quality of life for your pet.

Comment: I'm not hurting. I've gone through this before. I really shouldn't have bothered coming on here. I was searching all over google to see if rats could go insane because she was acting weird, but this was just a waste of time. My dd probably won't put her down yet anyway. I hate having her still. It's not that I don't love her just I have developed allergies and I really want to get a fish or a lizard. She can't die fast enough and I know that sounds insensitive but I'm tired of the hurt. From allergies from the memories of my other rats that are gone and from her own pain and suffering.